# Assist with react feeding properties to function fed to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React application involving components, so I will explain as follows:

1. pmMerge.jsx

- Two items in state to store objects for patient1 or patient2

```
const [patientOne, setPatientOne] = useState({})
const [patientTwo, setPatientTwo] = useState({})
```

2. handleOnChange function

- Function is triggered when item is selected in the asyncSelect
- It goes to an endpoint to get complete info for the person selected and stores the object in patientOne or patientTwo

function handleOnChange()

3. jsx return

- This runs a component which does the async select
- Two functions are fed to the component;
- LoadOptions goes to an endpoint to get the options for the select input
- HandleOnChange (see above)

```
<PmAsyncSelect                 
  asLabel = 'Select Patient One'
  inputId = 'patOneSelect'
  inputName = 'patOneSelect'
  patientNum = 'one'
  handleOnChange = {handleOnChange}
  loadOptions = {loadOptions}
/>
```

4. component PmAsyncSelect.jsx

- It does the 'asyncSelect' using the two functions fed from the parent

```
<AsyncSelect
  openMenuOnClick={false}
  isClearable={true}
  defaultValue={null}
  onChange={handleOnChange(patientNum='one')}
  loadOptions={loadOptions}
/>
```

5. So now here is what I am trying to do:

On the page, we will be doing two separate async selects for patientOne and patientTwo. These will operate independently of each other.

I am trying to pass a property the 'handleOnChange' function so it knows which constant it needs to update (either patientOne or patientTwo), for example, `patientNum = 'one'`.

This is the part that is breaking - if I remove that property from the calling of `handleOnChange` everything works, but it cannot do one or the other like it should. I am pretty sure I am just not defining the property for 'handleOnChange' properly and that is why my app is getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current version of AsyncSelect is not passing handleOnChange as a function (`handleOnChange`) but is instead calling handleOnChange (`handleOnChange(...)`) and passing it's return value.

It seems like you need to implement AsyncSelect like this:

```
<AsyncSelect
             
    openMenuOnClick={false}
    isClearable={true}
    defaultValue={null}
    onChange={() => handleOnChange(patientNum)}
    loadOptions = {loadOptions}
/>
```

Comment: hello Bankbuilder - that definitely helped, made it so the app was not 'broken' - not fixed all the way though; the handleOnChange function still has a problem with the inputs; i did not show that whole function, i will try and update this and show that tomorrow... thanks!

Comment: hello again:  was not able to resolve the problem i alluded to, but your answer fixed the 'core' issue, and resolved the error i posted about, but as I am sure you know, once you fix one problem - that can uncover another problem that it could not reach before since it was bombing!  thanks!

Comment: Good luck gman_donster!